# Setup wpf .net proyect works but exe didn´t find

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, installation, visual-studio-2019

I´m tring to instal an app that I create with wpf (.NET 4.8), I used Microssoft Visual Studio Installer Projects and these are the steps that I follow:

1. I add a new proyect to the solution.
2. In Aplication Folder/Add/Project Output...
3. Primary output and Localized resorces.
4. Finally i Build the solution

I loock for the exe in the folder instalation but only there is a .ddl and a .josn.
Thanks.

Comment: Open the csproj file with notepad.  Check the paths of files.  I sometimes edit the path names in the csproj to use relative paths rather than fixed paths.  When a project is added usually VS will include full path name.  If you are installing in a different drive (like d: instead of c:) you may get errors.

Comment: I opened the file, but there aren´t paths. I have to tags (PropertyGroup and ItemGroup).

Comment: Go to project bin folder in build machine.  Try running the exe file in both the debug and release folders.  See if both work.  Normally the debug will work and the release will not work.  Check file date of both exe.  You may need to compile the release build if older than debug.  VS usually runs the debug version and the publish uses the release build.

Comment: Both .exe file works well

Comment: I had build both projects.

Comment: When you add a project to a main vs project you should always browse to the debug folder of the child project.  This way any changes to the child project will automatically be recognized and the child project will recompiled and dll from child will be added to main project.

Comment: I understand the fact, but I have the dll file but not an .exe

Comment: Same applies to a dll or any executable output of a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sted of Primary outPut, I have used PublishItemsOutputGroup.

Answer (score 0):

@ michu. According to your description, there may be a problem with your steps. Please check if the following steps are same with you .

1.Download and install Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects.

【Click **Extensions** in Visual Studio to search for **Microssoft Visual Studio Installer Projects** to download and install】

2.Create a Setup Project named Setup.

3.Add WPF software primary output DLL file into installer.

【Right-click Setup and select **Add**/**Project Output...**and modify the "**Add Project Output Group**" page as follows:】

[image]

4.Add installer setup icon file.

【Right-click Setup and select **Add**/**File...** and add the APP.ico file as application icon: (I did not add an application icon here.)】

5.Create WPF software shortcut for Desktop.
[image]

【Right-click on the generated file and rename it to apptest and drag it to **User's Desktop**. Then right-click apptest in **User's Desktop** and select **Properties Window…**:】

[image]

[image]

6.Configure the details of WPF software properties.
[image]

7.Build Setup Installer.

【Click **Build** and select **Batch Build** and modify as follows:】
[image]

[image]

8.Install.

After the installation is complete, you can see the exe in the installation path.
[image]

Comment: Hi, I have been following your steps, but sadly the .exe haven´t created.

Comment: Hi, @ michu. Could you show me the specific structure of your WPF program? Please provide me more detailed steps and related information to reproduce and analyze the issue. For more Microsoft Visual Studio installer project information, you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/2kt85ked(v%3dvs.100)).

Comment: Don´t worry I just fix the problem, In sted of Primary outPut, I have used PublishItemsOutputGroup. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to find out why it didn't work for me, so I'll publish a possible solution here as well.

If you defined a publishing profile, you **need** to select it for the product output group and set it in `PublishProfilePath` (Right Click on Publishing Group -> Properties).